# Submitting form input array via ajax and saving with mysql/php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, serialization

I've got some code below which has been working fine for one input field. However I have some code that appends extra fields into the form if you click a div called #addForm, and the inputs have the name of name="itemName[]".

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('body').on('click', '.save', function(e) {
            var string = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "add_room.php",
                data: string,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){
                    $('#message').text('The id of the inserted information is ' + data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#addForm').on('click', function(){
            $('<label for="itemName[]">Item</label><input class="itemName" type="text" name="itemName[]"><label for="itemCondition">Condition</label><input class="itemCondition" type="text" name="itemCondition"><div class="save">Save Item</div>').fadeIn(500).appendTo('#mainForm');
        });
    });
    </script>
```

As you can see, I've got most of the code there, yet I get confused with serialize and I'm not sure how I should be handling this on the php end.

This is my script so far for the php:

```
<?PHP

    include('dbConfig.php');

    $item = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['itemName']);

    if ($stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT test (test_title) VALUES (?)"))
    {
        // Use an s per variable passed to the string, example - "ss", $firstname, $lastname
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $item);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        echo $db->insert_id;
        //echo "success";
    }
    // show an error if the query has an error
    else
    {
        echo "ERROR: Could not prepare SQL statement.";
    }
?>
```

Comment: I think putting `print_r($_POST['itemName'])` somewhere in your PHP will help you.

Comment: You might find the jQuery Form Plugin helpful: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: adding print_r does help. I can see that now my form is submitting the information as an array. I just need to find out a way to strip these out and insert them seperately but to the same parent id. what i got in return was: The id of the inserted information is Array ( [0] => sdsdsd [1] => sdsd [2] => asdasdasd )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call [`serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) on a `<form>` or a set of form fields and not a button (I guess)
If the button is in the form then try,

```
var string = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
```

if you don't have a form just select all the inputs you need

```
var string = $('#input1,#nextone,#somefield').serialize();
```

Comment: Hey mate, the problem with the second option is that there is no predefined amounts, the user will add the input fields they need so it needs to be automatic. Doing the first option seems to break the system, though i would assume that's my fault. The php is killed. Any suggestions?

Comment: @AndyHolmes give all the inputs a class then select them by their class. `$('.input_class').serialize()`

Comment: Its okay, i missed the [] in my php script. It's now printing an array like - The id of the inserted information is Array ( [0] => sdsdsd [1] => sdsd [2] => asdasdasd ). Just need to split these and add them seperately to the database. Will i need to use something like an unserialize?

Comment: @AndyHolmes its an array so you just reference them through their index. `[0]` will give you `sdsdsd` etc

Comment: Can you give me an example? Not entirely 100% on the whole array thing at the momen

Comment: @AndyHolmes `$items = $_POST['itemName'];`, so `$items[0]` will be equal to `sdsdsd`

Comment: Okay but i need this to trigger saving to my database for each item within the array, i get that. But whatever i try array wise on the php it just doesnt work. Is anyone able to help fix my code with the php i have provided?

Comment: Not to worry i sorted it! wrapped the wrong bloody bit in the foreach haha

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['itemName']` is going to be an array.  You need to treat it as such (i.e. not try to perform `real_escape_string()` on it).

You would also need to either loop through the array doing separate insert queries, or build a single query which insert all values.

From a javascript standpoint, I am guess you need to serialize the form as opposed to the button that is clicked.  I just noticed @Musa posted an answer on this, so follow that instruction.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view

```
var string = $(this).serialize();
```

`this` in the above context is most likely to be reference of the DOM element which has a class name `save`, it could be a button for submission of the form.

However, the correct element that serialize() is called of should be a form element.

I think that's why you can't get anything from server side,

```
$_POST['itemName']
```

I suggest, you can start with have a look at `$_POST` object, then figure out how to extract the data you need from it.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Form

```
<form method="POST" class="save" action="add_room.php">
<input type="text" name="itemName[]"/>
<input type="text" name="itemName[]"/>
<button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).on("submit",".save",function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.post($(this).attr("action"),$(this).serialize(),function(r){
//result
alert(r);
});
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T438t/)

PHP

```
$item = $_POST['itemName']

foreach( $item as $key => $val ) {
  //iterate itemName values
}
```

[PhpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/et5-hw6)